# find cov(Y1,Y1) given expected value and variance

Tags: statistics, probability

I am given two random variables $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ and:

- $E(Y_1) = 4$
- $E(Y_2) = -1$
- $V(Y_1) = 2$
- $V(Y_2) = 8$

I am asked to find $Cov(Y_1,Y_1)$

I know $Cov(Y_1,Y_2) = E(Y_1Y_2)-E(Y_1)E(Y_2)$

I'm not sure if it is a typo, but it says $Cov(Y_1,Y_1)$ NOT $Cov(Y_1,Y_2)$

The answer is $2$, but i'm not sure how to get $E(Y_1Y_2)$ from the information given, or why it's asking for the Cov of the same variable?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You do not seem to have any information about the relationship between $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ and so cannot say anything about the covariance between them.  It could be anywhere between $-4$ and $+4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$cov(Y_1,Y_1)=var(Y_1)=2$ 
This follows from the definition of covariance:

$cov(Y_1,Y_1)=E(Y_1\cdot Y_1)-E(Y_1)E(Y_1)=E(Y_1^2)-E(Y_1)^2$

Comment: love how it says that nowhere in my book... Thanks!

Comment: This follows from the definition. See above edit.

Answer (score 2):

Cov$(Y_1,Y_2) = \text{Cov}((Y_1-E[Y_1])(Y_2-E[Y_2])) = E[Y_1 Y_2]-E[Y_1]E[Y_2]$

Now let $Y_2 = Y_1$

Then Cov$(Y_1,Y_2) = E[{Y_1}^2] -(E[Y_1])^2$

This equation should look familiar...the variance of $Y_1$

Comment: nicely explained